# Connecting a Samsung Galaxy S3 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, android, mtp

In 13.04, whenever I connect an Android device, one of three things happens:

1 . It mounts successfully (maybe once out of 3 attempts)

2 . It fails to mount with the following error message:

> **Oops! Something went wrong.**
>
> Unhandled error message: Unable to open MTP device

3 . This one occasionally happens:

> Unhandled error message: No such interface `org.gtk.vfs.Mount' on
> object at path /org/gtk/vfs/mount/1

**Regardless of activity (even when successfully mounted) it will continuously spam the following error message:**

> **Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android**
>
> Unable to open MTP Device '[usb:003,00x]'

where **x** seems to be an arbitrary number below 10 and continues counting up with each new error message until the device is unplugged.

I've also just noticed that **even if it mounts successfully, it unmounts after about 30 seconds** and starts spamming the error message above. The Android device is unlocked, always on and fully charged. ADB seems to function normally.

Any suggestions?

Further info: this happens on both a stock Samsung S3 and an Xperia Arc S running a custom AOSP based ROM.
I've also tried the steps outlined in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055304/unable-to-mount-samsung-android-in-ubuntu), but the problem persists.

**UPDATE:** After doing a dist-upgrade (May 8th 2013), the Xperia Arc S on AOSP ROM now mounts and behaves normally. The S3, however, still behaves as described above.

**UPDATE**: After careful observation, ABD does not, in fact, behave normally. If the error message above appears *while sending an app* to the device, the attempt is aborted with an error message saying that the device is unavailable.

Comment: I no longer have access to an S3, so am unable to verify any answers. Should I close the question?

Comment: i had problems mounting Android and windows devices by myself.
check that ur device is unlocked and is in proper mode i.e. data transfer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems mounting Android devices by myself. Maybe you forgot to unlock your android device. As long the security log is activated (pattern or number) the fuse-MTP module will not be able to mount the device, which is quite sensible from a security view.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this will help, but mine does that "unable to mount" repeater to, but that  is because it is recognized as a device, but then 10 seconds later it disappears and reappears as a usb media device, then it mounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

If the ppa don't run test the unestable ppa,i think that this run for you, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The article you linked is about installing 13.04's version of GVFS in earlier versions of Ubuntu. How will this help someone who already has 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

Install mtpfs. below is the command to install it

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

`mtpfs` is a FUSE filesystem for Media Transfer Protocol devices.

disconnect your device, restart your laptop (this might not be required in some cases) and reconnect to get it working. i've tested this on some android devices.